# How do you deploy multiple docker containers to gcloud using Travis CI?

Tags: linux, docker, google-compute-engine, travis-ci, gcloud

I am having trouble accessing my gcloud compute engine via Travis-CI so I can have CI/CD capabilities.

So far using my current code I am able to use my git repository to start up docker containers on Travis CI to see that they work.

I am then able to get them to build, tag, and deploy to the google cloud container registry with no issues.

However, when I get to the step where I want to ssh into my compute instance to pull and run my containers I run into issues.

I have tried using the `gcloud compute ssh --command` but I run into issues with gcloud not being installed on my instance. Error received:

If I try running a gcloud command it just says gcloud is missing.

```
bash: gcloud: command not found
The command "gcloud compute ssh --quiet --project charged-formula-262616 --zone us-west1-b   instance-1 --command="gcloud auth configure-docker "" failed and exited with 127 during.
```

I have also tried downloading the gcloud sdk and running the docker config again but I start receiving the Error bellow.

```
bash
Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
Using default tag: latest
```

**I am able** to ssh into it using putty as another user to pull from the repository with no issues and start the containers and have the gcloud command exists.

The only thing I could think of is the two accounts used for ssh are different but both keys are added to the instance and I don't see where I can control their permissions. I also created a service account for travis ci and granted it all the same permissions as the compute service account and still no dice...

Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

My travis file looks like this

```
sudo: required
language: generic
services:
  - docker
env:
  global:
    - SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
    - CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1

cache:
  directories:
    - "$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/"
before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_0c35eebf403c_key -iv $encrypted_0c35eebf403c_iv
    -in secrets.tar.enc -out secrets.tar -d
  - tar xvf secrets.tar
  - if [ ! -d "$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin" ]; then rm -rf $HOME/google-cloud-sdk; export
    CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1; curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash; fi
  - source $HOME/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file service-account.json
  - gcloud components update
  - gcloud components install docker-credential-gcr
  - gcloud version
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - chmod 600 deploy_key_open
  - echo -e "Host $SERVER_IP_ADDRESS\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
  - ssh-add deploy_key_open
  - gcloud auth configure-docker

  # - sudo docker pull gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-client
  # - sudo docker pull gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-nginx

deploy:
  provider: script
  script: bash ./deploy.sh
  on:
    branch: master
```

and the bash script is

```sh
# docker build -t gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-client:latest -t gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-client:$SHA  -f ./client/Dockerfile ./client
# docker build -t gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-nginx:latest -t gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-nginx:$SHA -f ./nginx/Dockerfile ./nginx
# docker build -t gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-server:latest -t gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-server:$SHA -f ./server/Dockerfile ./server
docker push gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-client
docker push gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-nginx
docker push gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-server
#  curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-274.0.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
#  tar zxvf google-cloud-sdk-274.0.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz google-cloud-sdk
#  ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
#  sudo docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq)
# echo "1 " | gcloud init 
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i deploy_key_open travis-ci@104.196.226.118 << EOF
source /home/travis-ci/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
gcloud auth configure-docker
sudo docker-credential-gcloud list
 sudo docker pull gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-nginx
 sudo docker pull gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-client
 sudo docker pull gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-server
 sudo docker run --rm -d -p 3000:3000 gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-client
 sudo docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-nginx
 sudo docker run --rm -d -p 5000:5000 gcr.io/charged-formula-262616/web-server
 sudo docker run --rm -d -v /database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_USER -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD -e POSTGRES_DB postgres 
EOF
```

Comment: What is the problem you need help with? Just showing us two config files with no explanation is not helpful. We're not going to install and run those to see what fails.

Comment: The current error I am running into right now is that when I ssh into my compute instance via travis ci I get errors saying I do not have permission to pull from my container registry. However when I review the compute instance service account permissions I do have read and write access to the container registry. So basically thats where most of my issues are right now.

Comment: Please update the question with those details. Show the _exact error_ you're getting, and which command generates the error.

Comment: ok I added the exact errors and what I believe is causing them

Comment: I added a few more errors and described the problem area more thoroughly. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted includes a link to [Authentication methods](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication) where suggests some mechanisms to authenticate docker such as:

```sh
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

And other more advanced authentication methods. I recommend that you check this out as it will guide you to solve your issue.

To install the `gcloud` command you can follow the guide in [Installing Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install). That for Linux are [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get).

Comment: I tried using it in my Travis CI file but no matter what after I ssh into my instance and attempt to pull my docker containers I get that permission issue. I have even tried running that after ssh into my instance and it still doesnt work also it is unable to find the gcloud command as well unless I download it again. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong... but thanks for the help

Comment: I have updated the answer. Have you tried to execute one and each of the commands of the script separately and check for the output?

Comment: I understand that you are working now with 2 computers: one local machine and GCE instace on GCP? Is this true? The ssh problem with gcloud is on your local machine?

Comment: I am using my local machine to develop and test my docker containers and I use putty to connect to the GCE instance just to test things out and see if everything is working correctly. However, when I try to ssh into it using a Travis CI file thats when I run into problems.

Comment: In order to use the `ssh` you can set your private key in the GCE instance and connect using (Git bash or Linux bash) with this guide https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools